# Achieve relative path in generated module imports with grpcio-tools

Tags: python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python, grpcio

I am generating modules from two different protos, which have some common proto file names.
From protos-1 ->

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=p1/protos/ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. p1/protos/common/*.proto
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=p1/protos/ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. p1/protos/p1-unique/*.proto
```

From protos-2 ->

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=p2/protos/ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. p2/protos/p2-unique/*.proto
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=p2/protos/ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. p2/protos/common/*.proto
```

Running above commands for p1 followed by p2 overrides the generated module `common` of p1. Hence, it has issues in the generated file `p1-unique_pb2.py`. (incorrect ref of `common` module)

I then tried to generate modules from protos-2 in a separate folder, with

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=p2/protos/ --python_out=./abc --grpc_python_out=./abc p2/protos/p2-unique/*.proto
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=p2/protos/ --python_out=./abc --grpc_python_out=./abc p2/protos/common/*.proto
```

but still the imports in `p2-unique_pb2.py` is absolute `from common import common_pb2 as common_dot_common__pb2` and hence referring to `common` module generated by `protos-1`

I tried several solutions provided.. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9575 but none helped in  solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically a ProtoBuf issue. From the description, I don't know if the `common/*.proto` is the same across `protos-1` and `protos-2`. If they are the same, I guess you won't be posting this issue at all. If they are different, you may try matching the folder structure with the proto package name.

For example, you have a proto file `bar.proto` with package name `p2.common`, then it should be placed at `./p2/common/bar.proto`. The `protoc` command can just take `proto_path=.`. If there are multiple projects, you can consider copying all proto files into a central place before compilation.

There are many known complaint about the Python import path generation, you can find more info in https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues.